# WinRT C# dynamic expression evaluator

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

There is a requirement in my application to evaluate string expressions during runtime in WinRT c# application.

Here are some example expressions:

```
strObj.Substring(10) + strObj.Substring(strObj.Length - 3) 
'001' + strObj.Substring(3) + '003'
```

Note: Above expressions will be defined in the backend and the application should  evaluate at runtime with users input.

I looked at DynamicExpresso, NReco and some other expression evaluators none of those works in WinRT environment. Is there any framework available in WinRT? or how can I achieve it in code?

Comment: I'm an author of NReco LambdaParser. It depends only on core .NET assemblies (System, System.Core) and I presume it should work under WinRT environment. Could you provide more details about why it doesn't work?

Comment: Hi @VitaliyFedorchenko I get this error when adding reference "Could not install package 'NReco 2.0.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinRT environment cannot reference usual class library until it compiled as portable class library (PCL). Portable libraries have a lot of restrictions on framework classes/methods usage (only subset of usual .NET classes is allowed); in most cases class library cannot be compiled as PCL without additional adoption for these restrictions.

I've investigated possibility of compiling NReco LambdaParser as PCL and got positive results. PCL-adopted version doesn't include flexible NReco Type Converters (they are based on ITypeConverter/TypeDescriptor which are not available for PCL) and use just Convert.ChangeType instead.

Download link: [NReco LambdaParser Portable (with source code)](https://nreco.codeplex.com/releases/view/617322)

The following code works fine with PCL version of LambdaParser:

```
var lambdaParser = new LambdaParser();
Func<string,int,string> left = (s,n) => { return s.Substring(n); };
var vars = new Dictionary<string,object>() {
    {"str1", "123456"},
    {"str2", "123"},
    {"Left", left} // custom function
};
var res = lambdaParser.Eval(
    "str1.Substring(3)+\" \"+str2.Substring(str2.Length-2)+\" \"+Left(str1,1)", vars );
Console.WriteLine("Res: {0}", res);
```

If you found that this PCL-version is usable I may publish its source code on GitHub and create Nuget package.

Comment: Awesome, I will checkout and let you know, thanks Vitaliy Fedorchenko!

Comment: Works like a champ! Currently its not recognizing Extended functions. Example: strObj.Right(10).Left(4) where Right & Left are extended functions. Is there anyway I can register those function to the parser?

Comment: Parser can invoke only 'real' methods of an object (I suggest your 'Right' and 'Left' are extension methods that are actually static methods). As alternative you can pass any number of custom functions into parser context and use them in the expression (see updated code example).

Answer (score -1):

You can also try [DynLan](https://dynlan.com) - it also supports PCL / net3.5 / net.core (https://github.com/b-y-t-e/DynLan). The library parses the code itself and execute it line by line. Here is small example with your expression (result == "klmnoprstuwxyzxyz"):

```
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dict["strObj"] = "abcdefghijklmnoprstuwxyz";

            object result = new Compiler().
                Compile(@" strObj.Substring(10) + strObj.Substring(strObj.Length - 3) ").
                Eval(dict);
```

You can also use variables inside you script, like that (result == "ABCDEPRSTU"):

```
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dict["strObj"] = "abcdefghijklmnoprstuwxyz";

            object result = new Compiler().
                Compile(
                    @" a = strObj.Substring(0, 5).ToUpper(); " +
                    @" b = strObj.Substring(15, 5).ToUpper(); " +
                    @" a + b ").
                Eval(dict);
```

Comment: Please try to avoid answers that only consist of a link. Add some example code or more information, etc.